# how to prevent jquery to load already existing scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I am trying to load jsp pages in another jsp page using `XMLHttpRequest`. so i want to prevent loading the included scripts and files if it already existed:

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/layouts/two-menu-2/records-sidebar-vertical.jsp"%>  



url="/schedule/calendar";


function openModalWin(url){

    $(".load-bar").show();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var content = document.createElement("div");
            content.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var div = content.querySelector("#mymodal");
            document.getElementById("mymodal").innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
            var contentScript = content.querySelectorAll("script");
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            var sc = "";
            $(".appendScripts").empty();
            for (var i=0; i<contentScript.length; i++){
                if(contentScript[i].textContent.trim()!=""){
                    sc += contentScript[i].textContent; 
                }else{
                    var scl = document.createElement("script");

                    scl.src = contentScript[i].src;
                $(".appendScripts").append(scl);

                }
            }
            script.textContent  = sc;
           $(".appendScripts").append(script);

          }
         $(".load-bar").hide();
        }

      };
      xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I am loading all the codes of `url/schedule/calendar` to the current page.
if the `/schedule/calendar` has `<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/layouts/two-menu-2/records-sidebar-vertical.jsp"%>` in it.

I want to prevent loading it to the current page as it already existing in current page

Comment: I don't think manually writing `XMLHttpRequest` s will solve your problem elegantly. If you can use a module bundler such as parcel or webpack, prefer that. If not use `requirejs` to de-duplicate modules.

Comment: try and remove more specific code and leave just a complete minimal example behind, that might improve the readability of the question